# CSS HR cutting at div?

Tags: html, css

I’d like to know if it was possible to prevent the HR element to not cut and just skip to when the div tag stops.

The tag is just a simple
`<hr>`

Here’s my full code : https://jsfiddle.net/6bk5c7xn/

Thanks!

Comment: What do you want to happen?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since the `div` element you are referring to (which should be "skipped", if I understand you correctly) is floated, you can add `clear: both` as a CSS rule for `hr`, which will place it *below* all floated elements that appear before it in the code:

```css
.boxed {
  border: 1px solid green;
  width: 30%;
  float: left;
  margin: 20px;
}

fact {
  font-family: verdana;
  font-size: 13px;
  color: "gray";
}

fact.q {
  font-weight: bold;
}

fact.l {
  text-decoration: underline;
}
hr {
  clear: both;
}
```

```html
.
<div class="boxed">
  <div style="background:#C0C0C0;">
    <smalltitle>Facts</smalltitle>
    <br>
    <br>
    <fact class="q">Primary use: </fact>
    <fact>making eggs</fact><br>
    <fact class="q">Egg/chicken (annual): </fact>
    <fact>100</fact><br>
    <fact class="q">Egg size: </fact>
    <fact class="l"></fact>mall - p</fact><br>
    <fact class="q">Temperament: </fact>
    <fact>Calm, Friendly</fact><br>
    <fact class="q">Recognized variety: </fact>
    <fact class="l"><a onclick="alert('Recognized variety:\n\nBearded Black, Bearded Blue, Bearded Buff, Bearded Gray, Bearded Partridge, Bearded Splash, Bearded White, Non-Bearded Black, Non-Bearded Blue, Non-Bearded Buff, Non-Bearded Gray.')">Detail</a></fact><br>
    <fact class="q">Egg color: </fact>
    <fact>Cream, Tinted</fact><br>


    <br>
  </div>
</div>
<div name="wikipediaStatment" class="divSector">
  <smalltitle>Wikipedia statement</smalltitle>
  <br><br>
  <downP>The Silkie is a breed of chicken named for its atypically fluffy plumage, which is said to feel like silk and satin. The breed has several other unusual qualities, such as black skin and bones, blue earlobes, and five toes on each foot, whereas most
    chickens only have four.</downP>
</div>
<br>

<hr class="solid">

<br> Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book.
It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop
publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum
```

P.S.: Note that I simply copied the code from your JS fiddle into a snippet here (and then added the CSS rule I wrote about) - if ever possible, you should add the code to the question as a snippet, not link to an external resource like JS fiddle.